# Passing Interface from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to figure out how to populate a specfic interface via a form in a view.  The interface is in a different project and namespace then that of my controller / view and is automatically generated for storing data in the database:

**Interface namespace and Code:**

```
DataAccess.DAL.IVehicle

namespace DataAccess.DAL
{
    public partial interface IVehicle
    {
        String vehicleName { get; set; }
        int maxSpeed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a controller which has an action method for receiving information from the form in the view:

**Controller Code:**

```
namespace coreproject.Controllers
{
    public class NewVehicleController
    {
        [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public JsonResult AddVechicle(IVehicle newVehicle)
        {
            // I expect that newVechicle is populated via the form
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I should be using Html.BeginForm in the view.  Below is some code I came up with what I understand would be needed in the view.

**View Code:**

```
<% 
//  This is not working, I am not sure how to tell the view I want the form 
//  to use the interface located in the following namespace.
@Model DataAccess.DAL.IVehicle;

using (Html.BeginForm("AddVehicle", "NewVechicle", FormMethod.Post))

//  Below I understand that I would need some code in the form of Html.EditorFor to 
//  populate the IVehicle interface in the form.  I have seen this as an example:    
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.VehicleName) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.maxSpeed) %>
<%:
} 
%>
```

The questions I have are twofold and are related to the view:

1. How do I tell the view I want to use an interface located in DataAccess.DAL, which resides in a different project and namespace than the view?
2. How do I populate the aforementioned interface in the form in order to pass it to the controller?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the "GET" part of the controller, is this the complete source for the project?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a lot of concepts here.

1. Go to Visual Studio and create a new MVC website.
2. Run it and see how it works.
3. Then go on google and lookup the concept of interfaces.
4. Go back to your newly created MVC website and see the difference to what you have postet here.

Edit:
What you are trying is not possible!
You are asking the MVC framework to create an instance of an interface, this is not possible!

What you must do is to have a concrete class in the Action parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddVechicle()
{
   return View(new Vehicle());
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult AddVechicle(Vehicle newVehicle)
{
   // I expect that newVechicle is populated via the form
}
```

you could then declare the "Vehicle" class as follows

```
public class Vehicle :IVehicle
{
    String vehicleName { get; set; }
    int maxSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

I havent testet if the view will accept an interface as a model, you might better change it into the class "Vehicle"

```
<%
// view name: AddVehicle
//  This is not working, I am not sure how to tell the view I want the form 
//  to use the interface located in the following namespace.
@Model Vehicle;

using (Html.BeginForm("AddVehicle", "NewVechicle", FormMethod.Post))

//  Below I understand that I would need some code in the form of Html.EditorFor to 
//  populate the Vehicle concrete class in the form.   
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.VehicleName) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.maxSpeed) %>
<%:
} 
%>
```

Comment: I understand that interfaces are usually used as abstract types and for polymorphism (dependency injection).  I knew this before I posted.  I am simply trying to see how I can pass an interface via a form to a controller.

Comment: I have gone ahead and solved the issue with regard to how to find the controller from the view when posting the form.  Now my only question is related with sending the interface to the controller.

Comment: Answer is updated... why do you want a "JsonResult", it seems wrong... Please post complete source.

Comment: The code posted here, minus whats in the view file are excerpts from a functional project, with of course, altered class / interface names.

I would like to point out that in your proposed answer you have not posted any code of what the view would need in order to make your suggestion work.

This whole "you can't do that!" kind of approach whilst leaving out crucial information in your proposed answer is not exactly what I would classify as helpful.  Feel free to update your answer by including the complete code that the view would require and if it works on my end i'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry if i was a bit impolite, but as you are not providing a complete sample, i can't provide a complete solution. If you use an interface in an action you will get an exception, saying it cant create an abstract class. Therefor "you can't do that!"

Comment: Fair enough, feel free to post some code for the view file that would make your model work so we can achieve some closure here.

Comment: I have not had time to look into your solution - more on this when I try it out.